# How to work with overrided methods

Tags: java, overriding

how can i **override** method from `superclass` in `Java`, how to do it with constructor also? And how can i call method or constructor of superclass?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should go through a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and demonstrate basic understanding of the problem.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override method in Java, you need to define new method in sub class with the same name and same types of parameters. Before defining you should write annotation `@Override`. To get access to method in superclass, you should write like that:

```
super.methodName(params..);
```

To call super class constructor write:

```
super(params..);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic example on `overriding` (**Inheritence**) below to understand :

```
public class Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Animal Eats");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

 @Override
 public void eat() {
    super.eat();
    System.out.println("Dog Eats");
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog mdog= new Dog();
    mdog.eat();
 }
}
```

**Output** :

```
Animal Eats
Dog Eats
```